# organizing iOS app that gets data from server?

Tags: xcode

I am making an app that uses http requests to display images of documents.  It will open up on a main page with options of documents and once you click on a document it will read images from the server (note there are like 200 images) and you can flip through the pages.  My question: how do a create an app that will get a bunch of images from the server without having to create a bunch of individual Xcode pages?  And it has to be able to do it with multiple books based on which one you click.  And it should be able to handle the addition of documents to the server.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question, by 'create page in xcode' you mean in 'interface builder'.
if you have much images you have to load, create and display them programmatically not with interface builder, and take care to load them asynchronously to not freeze your app ( the responde of how you do is in your other question about cacheing images ;) ).